# Symfony 1.4 doctrine Update from image doSave()

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I'm using Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine, when I update a row with a form, it seems that the form not invoke `doSave()` method...

I use `doSave()` method when I upload an image and use `sfThumbnail`.

What can I do?

Example:

```php
protected function doSave($con = null) {
parent::doSave($con);

$thumbnail = new sfThumbnail();
                    $thumbnail->loadFile($upload->getTempName());
                    $thumbnail->save();
}
```

Comment: where are you defining this method?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in `postSave()`, it will be better there. Read [this page of the doctrine documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/hu/event-listeners%3arecord-listeners) if you don't know what I'm talking about.